# Cannot convert from Stream<T> to boolean

Tags: java, java-8, spring-webflux, java-9

I'm trying to filter a list of objects say BOLReference based on a key which is present in the inner object of one of the List of Objects of this BOLReference.

```
List<BOLReference> bolRef = complianceMongoTemplate.find(findQuery, BOLReference.class);

Optional<BOLReference> bref = bolRef.stream().filter(br -> br.getWorkflowExceptions().stream()
                        .filter(bk -> bk.getBusinessKeyValues().get(businessKey)
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("ABCD1234"))).findFirst();
```

While doing so I'm getting error as :

```
Cannot convert from Stream<WorkFlowExceptions> to boolean
```

My BOLReference looks like below:

```
private String ediTransmissionId;
private List<WorkflowExceptions> workflowExceptions;
```

And my WorkflowExceptions looks like:

```
private String category;
private Map<String,String> businessKeyValues;
```

Comment: the *structure* of given code:`...stream().filter( ...stream().filter( ... )  ).findFirst()` - you should note that the outermost `filter`  got the result of the innermost `filter`, that is, a `Stream`  - but the outermost `filter` needs a `boolean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Optional<BOLReference> bref = bolRef.stream()
    .filter(br -> 
        br.getWorkflowExceptions().stream()
            .anyMatch(bk ->
                bk.getBusinessKeyValues().get(businessKey)
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("ABCD1234")))
    .findFirst();
```

Failing `anyMatch` I think.

Comment: If I want to get the corresponding map i.e Map<String,String> businessKeyValues from the WorkflowExceptions List of BOLReference, what do I have to do?

Comment: @MiraDevi ask a new question, explaining what you want, and providing the attempted code. Today I have no more time, and do not am totally certain. A collect with grouping would do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

A filter clause does not return a boolean but a stream. This causes a problem because your first filter expects a boolean result, but gets a stream from the second filter. You can use `anyMatch` instead to achieve the desired result.

You can make stream expressions more readable by formatting them on more lines and extracting complex logic into methods.

You could fix & refactor it like this:

```
String businessKey = null;
String targetValue = "ABCD1234";

Optional<BOLReference> bref = bolReferences.stream()
    .filter(br -> br. hasBusinessKey(businessKey, targetValue))
    .findFirst();
```

And:

```
public class BOLReference {

    // ...

    public boolean hasBusinessKey(String key, String value) {
        return getWorkflowExceptions().stream()
            .anyMatch(wfe -> wfe.hasBusinessKey(key, value));
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class WorkflowExceptions {

    // ...

    public boolean hasBusinessKey(String key, String value) {
        return getBusinessKeyValues().get(key).equalsIgnoreCase(value);
    }
}
```